# My cat tried to tuck me in bed. What does it mean?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, sleep

My cat, Morris, wanted to spend time with me in my room alone.

I took in 5 cats from his family, including him, in the house.  They would have been feral cats otherwise.

Only 2 of them love to spend time alone with me in my room, as we would cuddle on the bed.

This one spends a little more time with me. Some times we just nap together or sleep together. But this time he did something different. Morris started what seemed like tucking me in. Only this time I was not covered. I wore just clothes, no blanket.

I would love to know what it means when they do that. When I was not covered, he started digging at the bedding. So what does it all mean?

Comment: Probably thinking that you may be too cold and should quickly cover up, by lying on the bed and putting on the blanket, and probably he may aid in the recovery process by warming you with his body heat by cuddling with you under the blanket. They are quite intelligent, you know.

Answer (score 6):

The behaviour is called **Kneading**. There could be multiple reason for it, but I'll go with *[Bedding Down](https://www.petmd.com/cat/behavior/evr_ct_why_do_cats_knead)*:

> The wild ancestors of domestic cats liked to lay down on soft, comfortable surfaces to either sleep or give birth to their young. By kneading down tall grass or leaves, cats were able to fashion a comfy spot to lay down in, and also possibly to check the ground for unwelcome visitors lurking under the foliage.